# I get more and better attention on Stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, questions, stackoverflow, programmers

I have been trying out "programmers" for quite a couple of weeks now and I feel disappointed.

The questions I have been asking are for the most part left completely unanswered or get a answered with an answer that I do not consider to be very good.

There the only exception to this is [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/269502/how-to-structure-a-loop-that-repeats-until-success-and-handles-failures) where I got very a few very constructive answers and well thought out answers (but that is just an exception).

Look at these questions. I have put alot of effort in them and I think that they are all very decent but all of them have yet to recive the answers that I want.

- [int * vs int [N] vs int (*)[N] in function parameters](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/269648/int-vs-int-n-vs-int-n-in-functions-parameters-which-one-do-you-think-i)
- [using macros to implement a generic vector](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/267657/using-macros-to-implement-a-generic-vector-dynamic-array-in-c-is-this-a-good)
- [using macros to protect assignment to global variables](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/268194/using-macros-to-protect-assignment-to-global-variables)

The only answer I got on [int * vs int [N] vs int (*)[N]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/269648/int-vs-int-n-vs-int-n-in-functions-parameters-which-one-do-you-think-i) felt wrong (everybody makes mistakes) so I made [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27878583/does-int-decay-into-int-in-a-function-parameter) on Stackoverflow to make sure. That question on Stackoverflow started reciving constructive comments and good answers immediately after I posted it.

I think that this is a problem. My time spent here is not rewarding. I think that I would have gotten alot better and more constructive design and readability answers on all my questions if I had put them on Stackoverflow instead. I get so much more attention there.

Answer (score 37):

It looks like the questions you've asked lie in the overlap between SO and PSE. Both sites could answer them, but they would give different kinds of answers, and since SO is bigger its answers will show up faster.

In my opinion, the three questions you've linked are all slightly more appropriate for SO, because they cannot be generalized to apply to languages other than C, and the answers depend more on the technical, language-lawyer consequences of a specific piece of code than any software design principles. You did successfully ask the "PSE parts" of those questions on PSE, and I think all three have decent answers (at least now they do), but their "SO parts" happen to be a lot more interesting. So it might be fair to say that SO is a more appropriate site for you.

This site tends to do much better with higher-level, language-agnostic issues like design patterns, architecture, API design, project management and so on.

Comment: Good answer! Do you know if it is possible to move (or copy) these questions to Stackoverflow where I can find people who can give me more detailed answers?

Comment: Questions can be "migrated" to other sites if enough high-rep users vote for it. But in your case, I think you did ask questions that are on-topic here, and they have decent enough answers already. So I would post new questions on SO that are rephrased just enough to be on-topic there, like you already did for that first one.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Good idea. I will modify them to fit SO more and ask them there. :)

Comment: Glad I could help =)

Answer (score 12):

In addition to the excellent answer by @lxrec, Programmers is so much smaller than StackOverflow that you just have to have a bit more patience.
It is not uncommon to only receive answers after several hours or even a day, where questions on SO get answers within seconds.

Comment: In my experience, however, the quality of the answers on SO that show up within seconds tends to be such that you think: "Hmm, this looks as if someone just threw it together within seconds", whereas the quality of the answers on P.SE that show up after a couple of days tends to be such that you think: "Whow, someone *really* spend a couple days thinking on this!" I'll take the latter one anyday.

Comment: Another point to raise is that SO will frequently generate multiple answers to a question whereas on Programmers, it's typical to see just one.