# I have copied these question to Stackoverflow. Now I want delete the ones here

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

After recieving good answers to [this question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7104/i-get-more-and-better-attention-on-stackoverflow) I have realised that some of my questions here are too language-specific to recieve the attention I want on here on "programmers".

I decided to copy them to Stackoverflow (with some rewriting to fit that site better).

Now when I am starting to recieve the answers I wanted Stackoverflow I think that it is time to delete the questions that are here.

The questions are:

- [using macros to implement a generic vector](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/267657/using-macros-to-implement-a-generic-vector-dynamic-array-in-c-is-this-a-good)
- [using macros to protect assignment to global variables](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/268194/using-macros-to-protect-assignment-to-global-variables)

I just wanted to let you know before I do it. To me it seems like the right thing to do but I want to know what you think first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't delete the questions. They appear to be on-topic questions that have answers. No need to take them away from others who could be helped by the information. It seems like you're doing the right thing.

Comment: Yeah. I started to doubt that decision after I posted this question here on meta. I noticed that one of the questions I linked have gotten a good answer since I last checked it. I will __not__ delete them.